# mov [0],cs shows error in dosbox

Tags: assembly

I got a problem when studying Assembly Language。

My dosbox report error for the following (8086cpu)

mov ax,1000 (passed)

mov ds,ax (passed)

mov [0],cs (error)

actually, it reports error every time I want to use [...]

Comment: And what error does it report? (Use [edit] to add it to your post. As a new user, please read the [tour]. Consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).)

Answer (score 2):

Second try. I guess the explicit segment prefix is missing on the address:

So instead of

```
mov [0],cs (error)
```

use an explicit prefix like this with properly set DS:

```
mov ds:[0], cs
```

I tested this with MASM and it assembles fine. The relevant opcode is:

```
8C /r   MOV r/m16,Sreg**(CS,DS,...)     Move segment register to r/m16.
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. What assembler xiaobio? What error?

Comment: `mov [mem], segreg` is a legitimate instruction... but perhaps incorrect syntax...

Comment: Thanks. You're correct, I confused the segment registers with control registers. Only immediates are not allowed with segment regs. I approprietely changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks zx485. I suspected that might be the issue, but I'm better at Nasm syntax...